# Kendo Datetime picker sending null into controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, html-helper, kendo-datetimepicker

I have a form using html helpers like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GuardarCliente", "Cliente"))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FechaDeNacimiento)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FechaDeNacimiento, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Fecha de Nacimiento...", style = "width:74%; " })
    <div class="row">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FechaDeNacimiento)                                
    </div>                            
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

   <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

}
```

But i want to transform this input into Kendo datetime picker like this:

```
 $("#FechaDeNacimiento").kendoDateTimePicker({
    value: new Date(),
    culture: "es-ES",
    dateInput: true
 });
```

Then when i cliked the save button is sending null value in the controller, why is that? How can i fix this with jQuery and not using the ASP.NET MVC wrapper of kendo?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if ASP.Net is rendering `id` attribute in your element, but try this:

```
$("#@Html.IdFor(m => m.FechaDeNacimiento)").kendoDateTimePicker({ ...
```

If that doesn't works, set the `id` by yourself:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FechaDeNacimiento, new { id = "FechaDeNacimiento"... })
```

Your widget initialization is ok I think.

Comment: @JuanJosé `$('[name="FechaDeNacimiento"]')` ??

Comment: sorry for making lose your time, it was just my mistake, the problem was for the culture, since in the bundle class I had a different reference for the culture that I put in the widget of kendo datetime picker. At least when i fixed that It worked back without problems

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the `input` element inside your HTML form? You'll need something like this:

```
<input id="FechaDeNacimiento" style="width: 74%" />
```

or, modify your existing razor code to add `id` attribute:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FechaDeNacimiento, new { @class = "form-control", id = "FechaDeNacimiento", placeholder = "Fecha de Nacimiento...", style = "width:74%; " })
```